# Gradle jar task executes wsclean task, why?

Tags: gradle, jar

I have a `build.gradle` file that looks like this

```
task wsimport{
    ....
}

task wsclean {
    delete "${destDir.path}/com"
}

compileJava.source = ["${projectDir}/src/main/java", "${projectDir}/src/main/generated"]
```

The `wsimport` task generates some java files that are needed from a `wsdl` file. The generation takes sometime, so I don't want it executed everytime I build a jar, or compile the program.

The `wsclean` task is meant to be used when the `wsdl` changes.

First I run the `wsimport` task and confirm the files are generated correctly, which they are!

But now when I run `gradle jar` the generated files are deleted. Why?

When I comment out the `wsclean` task, The `jar` task continues successfully. Why is gradle calling `wsclean`.

**Note:** I am dead sure I did not ***explicitly*** create `jar.dependsOn wsclean`

One theory I'm holding is that `jar` task executes `*clean` tasks. If so, how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem. My guess is that it **configures** the wsclean task, but doesn't **execute** it. I.e. you probably put the cleaning code in the configuration of the task instead of the execution.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not trying to execute it, I'm trying not to execute it

Comment: I understand that. What I'm saying is thet the error is most probably in what is hidden behing the `.....` in the wsclean task. The configuration code is executed whatever the task you start. The execution code is executed only if the task is part of the graph. But since we don't know anything about this task, we can't tell much.

Comment: @JBNizet `delete "${destDir.path}/com"` is all that is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
task wsclean {
  delete "${destDir.path}/com"
}
```

you need

```
task wsclean << {
  delete "${destDir.path}/com"
}
```

or

```
task wsclean {
  doLast {
    delete "${destDir.path}/com"
  }
}
```

Otherwise, the deletion is executed as part of the configuration phase, which happens on every build, whatever the task launched. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: I understood the comment now!